# OpenCV improve first GPU call and reduce time overhead

Tags: c++, opencv, video, opencl

I have some simple OpenCV code that  is something like this:

```
        TIMING_START(T1);
        cv::cvtColor(fi.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ), fi_gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
        TIMING_STOP(T1);
        TIMING_START(T2);
        cv::threshold(fi_gray, fi_gray, 70, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        TIMING_STOP(T2);
        TIMING_START(T3);
        cv::Canny(fi_gray, canny_output, 1, 255, 3);
        TIMING_STOP(T3);
```

The thing I try to accomplish works fine so what the code does is not the problem. The problem is the time overhead it needs because I use my integrated GPU and OpenCV 3.3 with OpenCL support to run on the iGPU. This works great for every call after the first. I know it takes time to initialize and compile gpu kernel code, but I use the code in a video application with the focus on realtime performance. So the first call and Image takes always like 1,5sec and obviously stutters the video. The calls after are done within < 10ms which is absolutely fine.

So is there a way to switch to the CPU variant while the GPU code compiles and use the GPU version afterwards or something? Just so I don't have that first time "lag".

Thanks for suggestions in advance!

Comment: There is one solution - do a dry run of the pipeline before the actual run, if possible. So everything gets set up.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added a Initialize() method that does a dummy call at the begining. This should be enough for my kind of application.

Answer (score 0):

See the comment to the above answer. After further reseach it seems like I can't easily avoid the overhead, but move it to the start of my application and use a dummy call at this point to have everything loaded before the videostream starts.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to cache binaries of any OpenCL kernels used, if you're not already doing that. (I don't know anything about OpenCV, so this advice is purely based on OpenCL alone.) Instead of building OpenCL programs from source, you can use [`clCreateProgramWithBinary()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateProgramWithBinary.html) with binary data saved from `clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARY_SIZES, ...)`/`clGetProgramInfo(program, CL_PROGRAM_BINARIES, ...)`. You'll still pay the compilation hit on first run, or rather on the first run after changing OpenCL implementation/device or even driver updates, but subsequent runs should be faster. (Of course, the advice about performing your initialisation as early as possible and "hiding" its runtime cost as much as possible still applies and can be combined with this.)